# Selecting 2nd li of second occurrence of a class

Tags: css

I have

```
  <ul class="biglist">
```

on many places of a page... in which i want to select only the second

```
 <ul class="biglist">
```

and in that again select second li and add color to it...

i currently have it like follows

```
 .biglist li:nth-child(2) {
  color:#ff0000;
 }
```

which i try to add...

```
  .biglist:nth-child(2) li:nth-child(2)
```

it does not selects the second list's second item. Tried in internet search and could not able to get suitable solution. can someone help pls ?

Here is my complete code...

```
<div class="vc_col-sm-4 wpb_column column_container ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="dt-fancy-separator title-left accent-border-color" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="dt-fancy-title bg-on" style="color: #ffffff;">
                <span class="separator-holder separator-left"></span>List of Places:
                <span class="separator-holder separator-right"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gap" style="line-height: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
        <section class="shortcode-teaser frame-fancy frame-on rotateInDownLeft animate-element">
            <div class="shortcode-teaser-content text-big">
                <ul class="biglist">
                    <li><p>New York</p></li>
                    <li><p>Ontario</p></li>
                    <li><p>London</p></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="gap" style="line-height: 30px; height: 30px;"></div>
    </div> 
</div> 


<div class="vc_col-sm-4 wpb_column column_container ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="dt-fancy-separator title-left accent-border-color" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="dt-fancy-title bg-on" style="color: #ffffff;">
                <span class="separator-holder separator-left"></span>List of Old Places:
                <span class="separator-holder separator-right"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gap" style="line-height: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
        <section class="shortcode-teaser frame-fancy frame-on rotateInDownLeft animate-element">
            <div class="shortcode-teaser-content text-big">
                <ul class="biglist">
                    <li><p>Mumbai</p></li>
                    <li><p>Tokyo</p></li>
                    <li><p>Bali</p></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="gap" style="line-height: 30px; height: 30px;"></div>
    </div> 
</div> 

<div class="vc_col-sm-4 wpb_column column_container ">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <div class="dt-fancy-separator title-left accent-border-color" style="width: 100%;">
            <div class="dt-fancy-title bg-on" style="color: #ffffff;">
                <span class="separator-holder separator-left"></span>List of New Ones:
                <span class="separator-holder separator-right"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gap" style="line-height: 10px; height: 10px;"></div>
        <section class="shortcode-teaser frame-fancy frame-on rotateInDownLeft animate-element">
            <div class="shortcode-teaser-content text-big">
                <ul class="biglist">
                    <li><p>Paris</p></li>
                    <li><p>Cairo</p></li>
                    <li><p>Delhi</p></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="gap" style="line-height: 30px; height: 30px;"></div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the rest of your markup?

Comment: you likely want to use `nth-of-type()` instead of `nth-child()` since `nth-child()` refers to how many other elements *of any type/class/etc* are around it. `nth-child(2)` would only target the ul if it's the 2nd child element of it's parent.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is this is not possible in CSS using nth-child or nth-of-type.

The class check is done after the nth element check, so if there are other ul elements between those of class biglist, you have no guarantee of selecting the ul you are looking for.

You need a JavaScript based solution.

For example, using Jquery:

```
uls = $("ul");
var bigListCount = 0;
for(i = 0; i < uls.length; i++)
{
  if($(uls[i]).hasClass("biglist")) bigListCount++;
  if(bigListCount == 2){
    $(uls[i]).css("color", "#ff0000");
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for this info.. this gives me a idea... do u know how to write this selector in jquery ?

Comment: @user2301765, the same way you would in css.

Comment: @user2301765 no problem. if you find that basic "ul" selector is returning a high number of ul elements, you might want to limit that by using a selector of ".shortcode-teaser-content ul" (or similar) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [:nth-of-type(N)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type):

```
ul.biglist li:nth-of-type(2) { background-color: #ff0000; }
```

Comment: yes this is selecting 2nd li of all 'biglist' lists. but i want it to select only the second li of second 'biglist' list.

Comment: @user2301765, I've tried cheating around, but I cannot get what you want with css alone, so Baraka might be right. Another note: having block elements (`p`) inside inline elements (`li`) is not good.

Answer (score 0):

`nth-of-type` checks the occurrence of an item in its direct parent. In the case of your HTML, inside a div there is only one `ul`. So what you have to do is first select one of the top level elements (the `column_container`) and then set its `ul`'s second `li` to red. Here you can see a working codepen example using your HTML.

https://codepen.io/tskjetne/pen/gWLKKr

For clarification, what I do is set the 2nd `column_container`'s `ul`'s 2nd `li` to color red.

Answer (score -1):

Given the knowledge now that you have elements in between the ULs, css only will not work.  Here's a jQuery solution:

```
if (($uls = $("ul.biglist")).length > 1){
  $uls[1].find("li:nth-child(2)").css({ color: "#ff0000" })
}
```

Comment: This relies on there being ONLY ul's of class biglist in the markup.
See this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRQxzM - I've added a ul in between the first and second biglist, your CSS no longer works. In short, I don't believe it is possible without javascript.

Comment: @jemminger - i tried it and it does not work... i have updated my whole html in the question. thanks for your help anyways